# Trouble with deploying Sonatype Nexus to Tomcat6 on Gentoo (log4j)

Tags: tomcat, log4j, nexus

I'm running a tomcat-6 server on Gentoo. I'm having trouble deploying Nexus to my tomcat server (nexus-war from the sonatype website, and tomcat6 via emerge). The localhost log displays the following when Nexus is started:

```
May 31, 2010 6:50:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonatype.nexus.web.LogConfigListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not create default log4j.properties into /dev/null/sonatype-work/nexus/conf/log4j.properties
        at org.sonatype.nexus.web.LogConfigListener.ensureLogConfigLocation(LogConfigListener.java:130)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.web.LogConfigListener.contextInitialized(LogConfigListener.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/null/sonatype-work/nexus/conf/log4j.properties (Not a directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:179)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:131)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.copyStreamToFile(FileUtils.java:1058)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(FileUtils.java:1018)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.web.LogConfigListener.ensureLogConfigLocation(LogConfigListener.java:126)
        ... 25 more
```

For some reason it looks for the sonatype-work folder in /dev/null. I have been unable to find a solution to this problem. The log4j.properties is located in /var/lib/tomcat-6/webapps/nexus-webapp-1.6.0/WEB-INF/log4j.properties and contain the following:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console
# CONSOLE
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.sonatype.nexus.log4j.ConcisePatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%4d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p - %c - %m%n
```

Has anyone had to deal with this before? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new one. In the war, the sonatype-work folder should default to ~/sonatype-work so if your environment has no user.home, this could cause what you see. You can try changing that default with an environment variable, see [here](https://docs.sonatype.com/display/NX/Nexus+FAQ#NexusFAQ-Q.HowcanIcontrolNexusconfigurationsinmyenvironment%3F) for details. If you still have trouble, ping us on the nexus-user list for more immediate support.

Comment: Hi there. You're right. The problem was that the tomcat user did not have a home folder assigned (the tomcat user is created automatically when emerging tomcat6). I updated /etc/passwd (the tomcat user previously had /dev/null set) and I am now able to deploy Nexus to Tomcat. :-)